# How to use Q_PROPERTY with static class members

Tags: c++, qt, static, qt5, qproperty

I'm new to Qt and came upon the Q_PROPERTY class, and was trying to set a static member using it. This is what I have so far:

```
class test{
      Q_OBJECT
      Q_PROPERTY(bool enabled READ enabled WRITE setEnabled)
    public:
    bool enabled() const{
        return m_enabled;
    }
    void setEnabled(bool enable){
        m_enabled = enable;
    }
    private:
    static bool m_enabled;
};
```

I'm getting compile errors when I try to run this so I'm not sure if there is a way to use static members with Q_PROPERTY. I've read through their documentation and other forum responses but I'm still unclear on the purpose of using Q_PROPERTY.

Comment: `I'm getting compile errors` - don't you think it would be interesting for us to know which compile errors you get? I would guess you don't get compile errors but linker errors.

Comment: Missing QObject parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about using static members with `Q_PROPERTY`. There are two problems with the code that you provided:

1. Your `test` class does not derive from `QObject`. Change it to this:

```
class test: public QObject
```

2. In your .cpp file, you need to define the instance of the static variable. This is true of any static members, not just for `Q_PROPERTY`. So in test.cpp, add this:

```
bool test::m_enabled = false;
```

With those changes, it should compile just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is going to need to inherit from `QObject` in order to use things such as `Q_PROPERTY` (`class test : public QObject`).

`Q_PROPERTY` is used to declare properties that can then interop with Qt's meta-object system. For example, you can set the property via the string name of the property, can interface with the property through QML, can animate the property using `QPropertyAnimation`, and `Q_PROPERTY` can be used to define properties that will show up within editors such as Qt Designer. Generally, a standard C++/Qt application will not need `Q_PROPERTY`.